# How does google analytics measure geographic location of visitors?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

We're using GA to measure the traffic on our intranet site and we would like to determine the geographical location of visitors. However, the stats don't make much sense because vast majority of users seems to be located in only two countries (and we have much larger facilities elsewhere where there is no traffic at all). Can this be because GA is only able to determine the geographical location of the two proxy servers we use as gateways to our internal network? And if so, is there any other way how to measure the geo stats using GA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The location is determined bases on ip. In your case the ip captured are only those of the proxy servers.